# How to speed up VueJS SPA?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a website written in *Laravel* and *InertiaJS (VueJS)*.
It has more than 60 pages.
InertiaJS stores all pages and components in these three files:

`/js/manifest.js`

`/js/vendor.js`

`/js/app.js`

The problem is the size of these files (Specially `app.js`) are getting so huge! The `app.js` is about 5MB.

I removed useless plugins and libraries, Also i refactored my code and it's all clean.

When i was only using Laravel for web development, I could load each page javascript and css files in it's own page. So speed of the page was pretty good. But when i migrated to VueJS it loads app.js and styles.css at once! It also extracts all styles in one file which is not ideal.

Also i use CDN, gzip compression, SSR and they are not helping too much to have better performance.

I want extract all components and pages into different javascript/css files and load them in their own pages when needed.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your app.js using code splitting. See if it'll reduce your load size:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

const App = () => import('./App.vue');
const Link = () => import('@inertiajs/inertia-vue/Link');
const plugin = () => import('@inertiajs/inertia-vue/plugin');
const BootstrapVue = () => import('bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.esm');
const IconsPlugin = () => import('bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.esm');
const Ziggy = () => import('ziggy-js');
const InertiaProgress = () => import('@inertiajs/progress');

Vue.component('inertia-link', Link)

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(IconsPlugin);
Vue.use(plugin)

InertiaProgress.init()

Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        route: (name, params, absolute) => Ziggy().then(ziggy => ziggy.route(name, params, absolute)),
    },
});

const app = document.getElementById('app')

if (app.dataset.page) {
    new Vue({
        render: h => h(App, {
            props: {
                initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
                resolveComponent: name => import(`./Pages/${name}.vue`).then(m => m.default),
            },
        })
    }).$mount(app)
} else {
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app'
    });
}
```

See this: [Inertia doc](https://inertiajs.com/code-splitting)

Comment: I really appreciate you. Inertia Docs Helped me with that.

Comment: Hi, i have the same problem here, When i follow inertia docs and do what documentation says, InertiaJs do not create javascript and style tags of extracted components in final output.

Comment: @MohammadZarifiyan is it a Laravel project? What do you mean by 'not creating js...'? Can you provide some codes?

Answer (score -1):

Are you loading all the pages at once?

I think you can try loading components only if required. We can use lazy loading and reduce `app.js`. Ref: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#with-webpack

```
        render: h => h(App, {
            props: {
                initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
                resolveComponent: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
            },
        })
    }).$mount(app)
```

This is my app.js file.

```
require('./bootstrap');

import {App, Link, plugin} from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import {BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin} from 'bootstrap-vue'
import route from 'ziggy-js';
import {Ziggy} from 'ziggy-js';
import {InertiaProgress} from '@inertiajs/progress'

Vue.component('inertia-link', Link)

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(IconsPlugin);
Vue.use(plugin)

InertiaProgress.init()

Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        route: (name, params, absolute) => route(name, params, absolute, Ziggy),
    },
});

const app = document.getElementById('app')

if (app.dataset.page) {
    new Vue({
        render: h => h(App, {
            props: {
                initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
                resolveComponent: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
            },
        })
    }).$mount(app)
} else {
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app'
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm using Inertia JS and Laravel, What all people are talking in this forum are about Vue Router and other stuff. :(

Please read whole question again.

Comment: Can you share your app.js code? Why do you have manifest.js and vendor.js files in your js directory? What I'm familiar with is that this directory only contains your shared components, layout files, pages, app.js and bootstrap.js files.

Comment: @viking i understand you are using Inertia, what i means is are you loading dynamically without code splitting. That would be the issue i am tried to say. I uploaded the whole file. Vue router is the main place to load these components. That's why I am talking about vue router.

Comment: I believe what @PyaeSone says about code splitting should resolve your problem. I don't think this is an Inertia bug. Your app.js doesn't code-split, it loads all your pages.